# Autodesk Spark Print Manager Operating Systems?

Tags: print-api

What operating systems are available for running the Autodesk Spark Print Manager? (https://spark.autodesk.com/developers/reference/printer-manufacturers/integrate-your-printer/integrate-your-printer-model)

I'm finding the documentation a little difficult to parse. It does *seem* that there are only build options for Windows or Mac, but I want to confirm.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly does that software do?  It wants me to make an account to see the documentation?  It it like octoprint?

Comment: Hey! Sorry for late reply... Basically it allows you to manage print queues, prepare basic DLP/FDM jobs, among other things. Kind of like the glue between a GUI and the firmware of the printer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked https://spark.autodesk.com/developers/reference/desktop-applications/print-manager. It seems that Print manager is a application written in JavaScript and its source code is available on [github](https://github.com/spark3dp/print-manager).

So you have to install node.js to run it. So you can use all major OS (win, mac, linux, ...).